# Proving there exists a real functions satisfying two integral equalities

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to show there exists a real function $H(x)$ ($C^{\infty}$) increasing with near infinity $H(x)=kx$ ($k$ is real and can be chosen) such that:

$$ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^\infty  H'(x)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{(-a+ib) H(x)} dx=A$$

and:

$$ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^\infty x^{-\frac{1}{2}-a-ib}   H'(x)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{(-a+ib) H(x)} dx=B$$

Where $\epsilon$ is a fixed real, $0<a<\frac{1}{2}$ and $A$, $B$ are complex numbers.
Intuitively finding such $H$ cseems possible as there is an infinity of possible $H$ functions and that it is not difficult to show that $H$ satisfying the firts equality exists but to prove that we can have both equality at same time is in fact complex and not obvious at all. Any idea on how to treat this ? Any advice ?